# Volume between paraboloid and plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d

I need to find the volume of the finite region enclosed between the surface

$$ y = 1 - x^2 - 4z^2 $$ and the plane $$y = 0$$

Here's what I've done:

$$ \int\int \left(\int_0^{1-x^2-4z^2}\mathrm{d}y)\right)\mathrm{d}A$$

where dA is the ellipse that the paraboloid projects down to in the x-z plane. For this ellipse, I've used the parametrisation

$$x = r\cos{\theta}, z = \dfrac{1}{2}r\sin\theta$$

and calculated the area in polar coordinates. Is this method legit?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds legit, what are the edges for $\theta$ and $r$?

Comment: r from 0 to 1, theta from 0 to 2pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're trying: $$\iint_A y \,\mathrm{d}A = 2 \int_{0}^{1}\!\!\int_{0}^{2\pi} (1-r^2) \cdot r \,\mathrm{d}\theta \,\mathrm{d} r$$

The scale factor of 2 is because without it the volume would be for between $y_2=1-x^2-z^2$ and the $x,z-$plane.  (You applied a scaled polar transformation to $z$).

Comment: Awesome, that's what I got in the end. Thanks :)