# Volume enclosed between $x=3y^2+z^2$ and $x=7$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, polar-coordinates

> Find the **volume** enclosed between the paraboloid $x=3y^2+z^2$ and the plane $x=7$.

I've tried cartesian but have struggled with the limits, is it possible to do this with polar coordinates?

Comment: You mean the volume? Duplicate with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765667/volume-between-paraboloid-and-plane?rq=1 ?

Comment: ah yes, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I have given the solution in a hand written image and hopefully it is clear and legible  Good Luck

[image]

Comment: if it were x^2=3y^2+z^2 and x=7 could you follow the same approach but replace the inner x integral limits by root(3y^2+z^2) and 7? Thank you

Comment: You could follow the same approach but this time the curve of intersection is gotten by equating $49 = 3y^2+z^2$ and parmeterize accordingly

Comment: I made a mistake, The integrand should be (7- (3y^2+z^2)) not the root, I will edit it

Comment: I have changed the solution. It is correct I believe.\